# Cómo seleccionar varios items en una recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Tras bastante esfuerzo he conseguido crear una recyclerView que funcione. También he conseguido obtener los datos de un item al pulsar sobre él, es decir, seleccionar un elemento de la lista. Pensaba que una vez conseguido eso el siguiente paso sería sencillo, ya que lo único que necesito es seleccionar varios a la vez, deslizando el dedo (swipe) y también seleccionando uno por uno.

El problema es que no sé cual es la mejor manera de lograrlo utilizando java, ya que he encontrado tutoriales pero utilizan kotlin.

Para crear la recyclerView he creado un adapter personalizado:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class rvQuestionsAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<rvQuestionsAdapter.ViewHolder>
        implements View.OnClickListener{

    // variable for our array list and context
    private ArrayList<Question> objectQuestionsArrayList;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;
    private Context context;

    // constructor
    public rvQuestionsAdapter(ArrayList<Question> objectQuestionsArrayList, Context context) {
        this.objectQuestionsArrayList = objectQuestionsArrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        // on below line we are inflating our layout
        // file for our recycler view items.
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.questions_rv_item, parent, false);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        DAOHelper d = new DAOHelper(context);

        Question question = objectQuestionsArrayList.get(position);

        holder.rvQuestionsQuestion.setText(question.getQuestion());
        holder.rvQuestionsAnswer.setText(question.getAnswer());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // returning the size of our array list
        return objectQuestionsArrayList.size();
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (listener!=null){
            listener.onClick(view);
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // creating variables for our text views.
        private TextView rvQuestionsQuestion, rvQuestionsAnswer;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // initializing our text views
            rvQuestionsQuestion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvQuestionsQuestion);
            rvQuestionsAnswer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvQuestionsAnswer);

        }
    }
}
```

He creado el XML para los items de la recyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--text view for our course name-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvQuestionsQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Question" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rvQuestionsAnswer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Answer"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <!--text view for our course description-->

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Y en el archivo java de la activity he creado el siguiente método para cargar la recyclerView:

```
public void listarQuestions(){

        ArrayList<Question> lista = d.obtenerQuestions();
        rvQuestionsAdapter = new rvQuestionsAdapter(lista, QuestionAnswerManagerActivity.this);
        if (!lista.isEmpty()) {

            rvQuestionsAdapter = new rvQuestionsAdapter(lista, QuestionAnswerManagerActivity.this);

            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(QuestionAnswerManagerActivity.this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, true);
            rvQuestions.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

            rvQuestionsAdapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    questionSelected = lista.get(rvQuestions.getChildAdapterPosition(view)).getQuestion();
                    answerSelected = lista.get(rvQuestions.getChildAdapterPosition(view)).getAnswer();
                    etQue.setText(questionSelected);
                    etAns.setText(answerSelected);
                }
            });

            // setting our adapter to recycler view.
            rvQuestions.setAdapter(rvQuestionsAdapter);
        }
    }
```

Utilizando código java, hay alguna manera de seleccionar varios items de la lista, para obtener su información? Cualquier ayuda se agradece. Un saludo.

Comment: Para esto tendrías que usar `SelectionTracker`. Realmente no hay un ejemplo completo [en la documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview-custom#select), pero conviene leer lo que se dice allí, pues si no usas las herramientas correctas podrías tener problemas de UI bloqueada y demás si el RV manejara muchos datos. [Aquí hay un tutorial en Java](https://medium.com/@Dalvin/android-recycler-view-with-multiple-item-selections-b2af90eb5825) donde se explica cómo implementarlo. Intenta eso y si hay algún problema nos dices.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias por la respuesta. He estado intentando probar el código de ese ejemplo pero no lo he conseguido. Pero ahora gracias a ti ya sé qué es lo que tengo que buscar por lo que estoy investigando sobre SelectionTracker para intentar hacer funcionar algún código. Como siempre, muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Hola @Javierungo no se si te servira esto pero es como lo hago yo.
**actividad_principal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#EEE">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**elemento_fila.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/text_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="10dp"
  tools:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

En item_row.xml android:clickable="true" es importante

**Main Activit.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<Model> mModelList;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getListData());
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private List<Model> getListData() {
  mModelList = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
      mModelList.add(new Model("TextView " + i));
  }
 return mModelList;
}
}
```

**Model.java**

```
public class Model {

private String text;
private boolean isSelected = false;

public Model(String text) {
  this.text = text;
}

public String getText() {
  return text;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
  isSelected = selected;
}


public boolean isSelected() {
  return isSelected;
}
}
```

**Recyclerviewadapter.java**
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

```
private List<Model> mModelList;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Model> modelList) {
  mModelList = modelList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
   return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Model model = mModelList.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(model.getText());
    holder.view.setBackgroundColor(model.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);
    holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            model.setSelected(!model.isSelected());
            holder.view.setBackgroundColor(model.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mModelList == null ? 0 : mModelList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private View view;
    private TextView textView;

    private MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    }
}
}
```

¿Como funciona? `onbindViewHolder()` El metodo vincula los datos del ArrayList a los objetos view. Entonces, al vincular a tiempo los datos a la vista, obtiene el único objeto de ArrayList que está `Model model = mModelList.get(position);` en la posición actual. Ahora debemos verificar si ese objeto en particular está seleccionado o no. Como esto,

```
model.isSelected()
```

que devuelve **true** o **false**. si ese objeto esta seleccionado, debemos cambiar el color de fondo de row_item. Para esto aqui esta el codigo.

```
holder.view.setBackgroundColor(model.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);
```

Si está seleccionado, cambie el color de fondo a cyan a white.

Para la selección necesitamos usar el `setOnClickListener()`. (aquí estoy usando solo un TextView. Así que estoy realizando un evento de clic en TextView). Aquí holder.view significa el single completo **item_row**. Al hacer clic, cambie los valores booleanos a **true** o **false**.

```
holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        model.setSelected(!model.isSelected());
        holder.view.setBackgroundColor(model.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);
    }
});
```

En su Actividad o Fragmento que aloja RecyclerView, puede obtener los objetos/elementos seleccionados como este:

```
String text = "";
for (Model model : mModelList) {
  if (model.isSelected()) {
    text += model.getText();
  }
}
Log.d("TAG","Output : " + text);
```

**Edición 1**: Restricción del usuario para seleccionar solo un elemento.

```
rivate int lastSelectedPosition = -1;  // declare this variable
```

...
// your code
...

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
final Model model = mModelList.get(position);
holder.textView.setText(model.getText());
holder.view.setBackgroundColor(model.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);
holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

```
        // check whether you selected an item
        
        if(lastSelectedPosition > 0) {
            mModelList.get(lastSelectedPosition).setSelected(false);
        }

        model.setSelected(!model.isSelected());
        holder.view.setBackgroundColor(model.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);

        // store last selected item position 

        lastSelectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();  
    }
});
}
```

Espero que sea util

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. He copiado el código en un nuevo proyecto para poder probarlo antes de adaptarlo a mi app. Aunque la parte de la respuesta con el código del adapter no se ha publicado correctamente no he tenido problema en solucionarlo. Sin embargo me aparecen un error en la MainActivity. En la línea `mModelList.add(new ColorSpace.Model("TextView " + i));` indicando lo siguiente: 'Model()' has private access in 'android.graphics.ColorSpace.Model'

Comment: @Javierungo porque haces un ** new ColorSpace.Model("Textview "+ i)); ** lo estoy haciendo en esa funcion es en la variable `mModelList.add(new "del Objeto de la lista del ReciclerView" )`.

Comment: Disculpa, quizá soy demasiado novato, no entiendo lo que quieres decir. He creado un proyecto nuevo y he creado las clases java que has indicado. No entiendo a qué te refieres con "del Objeto de la lista del ReciclerView". Si tengo las mismas clases y objetos que has indicado, no debería usar el mismo código (incluyendo esa línea)?